# I am looking for a general solution for $xy+x+y=n^2$ anyone able to help?

Tags: number-theory, elementary-number-theory

Is there a general formula for any $x$ and $y$ such that $xy+x+y=n^2$ for rational numbers (and some $n$?)

Thanks =)

Answer (score 4):

A hint/suggestion: add $1$ to both sides, getting $xy+x+y+1=n^2+1$.  You should be able to factor the LHS now and see how to get values of $x$ and $y$ from any $n$ such that $n^2+1$ is composite.